# How can I design good database structure for competitive platform?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database-design, database-schema, database

I am developing web site for competitive platform where different students can participate in regular (every day) contests (each lasting for 3 hours). Each contest has say 100 multiple choice questions. Then after contest ends, the results of all participants sorted by number of total points are published.

I am using MongoDB with Meteor framework. I have already implemented this but I realized that the database design was really not good.

Is there any better way I can design database structure which then can be scaled for 10k users?

So, I had the following database design (from the high-level point of view):

**Users**: [their data, test_1_result, ..., test_n_result]

**Questions**: [course(one of 15 courses), body, answer(A,B,C,D,or E), variant_A, variant_B, ..., variant_E, and other things describing question]

**Results**: [user_email, user_name, user_details, number_of_points_for_course_A, number_of_points_for_course_B, ..., number_of_points_for_course_Z, total_points,]

Or in other words, could you please provide me any materials where I can learn more practical knowledge about how to design such competitive contests platforms?

Comment: general rule for mongodb is normalize everything on the write

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

There are serveral people writing blog posts on both load testing, scaling meteor and how to plan and design a effective database schema. The Meteor chef wrote a post about how you desgin and use database shcema in Meteor https://themeteorchef.com/blog/managing-data-in-meteor-applications. To test the effcieny on your current structure use a load tester, such as https://github.com/alanning/meteor-load-test or https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-down, or the hosted tools from Kadira https://kadira.io/. Kadira also provides a course teaching you how to craft "fast and bullet proof meteor applications" https://bulletproofmeteor.com/basics/introduction.